# apt-get wants to remove MariaDB on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, apt-get, mariadb

I've set up my server to use MariaDB and used the installation instructions on the web page. It worked quite well. Now, if I want to `dist-upgrade`, apt-get wants to replace MariaDB with MySQL:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmariadbclient18 mariadb-client-5.5 mariadb-client-core-5.5 mariadb-server mariadb-server-5.5 mariadb-server-core-5.5
...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient18 mysql-common
```

Why does apt-get want to do this? How can I stop apt-get from doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a known problem, with an already-filed bug report: [see here](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-3882). The conflict arises because mysql and mariadb use conflicting versions of the library *libmysqlclient18*.

The quick fix is to give mariadb a higher priority than mysql, I have done it like this:

```
 echo -e "Package: libmysqlclient18\nPin: origin mirror2.hs-esslingen.de\nPin-Priority: 1000" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/mariadb-mysqlclient18
```

(This is for my mirror, of course... You'll have to adjust the above command to your mirror).

I agree it should be fixed upstream, but in the meantime...

Comment: This works pretty well for "upgrade", but still doesn't work for "dist-upgrade" (apt-get still wants to remove mariadb). Do you have a solution for that case too? Thanks!