# apt-get wants to autoremove core packages

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I upgraded to PHP 5.6RC4 today on my Debian Sid server (x64):

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  perl perl-base perl-modules
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.9 g++-4.9 gcc-4.9 gcc-4.9-base libasan1 libatomic1 libcilkrts5 libgcc-4.9-dev libgcc1 libgomp1 libitm1 liblsan0 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.9-dev libstdc++6 libtsan0 libubsan0 php-pear php5 php5-cli
  php5-common php5-curl php5-fpm php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-readline python-pil
28 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 762 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Now, when I do `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt-get autoremove` I get the following:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  console-setup console-setup-linux debconf-i18n dictionaries-common iamerican ibritish ienglish-common ispell keyboard-configuration libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tree-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl liblocale-gettext-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl
  libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libuuid-perl libwww-perl libxml-libxml-perl libxml-parser-perl
  libxml-sax-expat-perl linux-base linux-image-3.14-1-amd64 linux-image-amd64 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.0 task-english tasksel tasksel-data texinfo
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-pm-perl libmodule-build-perl libmodule-signature-perl libpackage-constants-perl libpod-readme-perl libregexp-common-perl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  perl perl-base perl-modules
3 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 42 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,102 kB of archives.
After this operation, 262 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

It seems it wants to remove a lot of Perl related packages (maybe because Perl hasn't been upgraded yet), but also `mariadb-server` (which I installed by myself, it's not a dependency), `linux-image-3.14-1-amd64` (which is my current kernel and has been pinned in `apt`), `tasksel` etc.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/744710/apt-get-wants-to-remove-mariadb-on-debian-wheezy) about MariaDB but that library hasn't been touched as far as I know.

Removing the Linux kernel doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Also I need the MariaDB server.

Does anyone know why this is suddenly happening? And how to fix it? Is there any command to check all dependencies again or locking all current packages? I don't want to pin all these packages manually (which doesn't even seem to work regarding to the kernel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: There seem to be some dependency problems with `libuuid-perl` and `perl-base`.

Edit 2014-08-18, looks like the deps/repos have been fixed; "works for me".

Troubleshooting steps, starting with the kernel issue:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd6`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-3.14-2-amd64 but it is not going to be installed

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64 "linux-image-3.14-2-amd64"`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   linux-image-3.14-2-amd64 : Depends: linux-base (>= 3~) but it is not going to be installed

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64 "linux-image-3.14-2-amd64" linux-base`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   linux-base : Depends: libuuid-perl but it is not going to be installed

Hmm, running into Perl here.

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64 "linux-image-3.14-2-amd64" linux-base libuuid-perl`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   libuuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable

Aha! `libuuid-perl` seems to require `perlapi-5.18.1`.

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64 "linux-image-3.14-2-amd64" linux-base libuuid-perl perl-base perlapi-5.18.1`

> Package perlapi-5.18.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>
> E: Package 'perlapi-5.18.1' has no installation candidate

Hmm. No `perlapi-5.18.1` available. Let's see what `perl-base` provides:

`apt-cache show perl-base`

> Package: perl-base
>   Source: perl
>   Version: 5.20.0-4
>   Essential: yes
>   Installed-Size: 5007
>   Maintainer: Niko Tyni 
>   Architecture: amd64
>   Replaces: libio-socket-ip-perl, libperl5.8 (<< 5.8.0-20), libscalar-list-utils-perl, libsocket-perl, libxsloader-perl, perl (<< 5.10.1-12), perl-modules (<< 5.10.1-1)
>   Provides: libio-socket-ip-perl, libscalar-list-utils-perl, libsocket-perl, libxsloader-perl, perl5-base, perlapi-5.20.0
>   Pre-Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), dpkg (>= 1.14.20)
>   Suggests: perl
>   Conflicts: defoma (<< 0.11.12), doc-base (<< 0.10.3), mono-gac (<< 2.10.8.1-3), safe-rm (<< 0.8), update-inetd (<< 4.41)
>   Breaks: autoconf2.13 (<< 2.13-45), libalien-wxwidgets-perl (<< 0.65+dfsg-2), libanyevent-perl (<< 7.070-2), libcommon-sense-perl (<< 3.72-2~), libfile-spec-perl (<< 3.4700), libgtk2-perl-doc (<< 2:1.2491-4), libio-socket-ip-perl (<< 0.29), libjcode-perl (<< 2.13-3), libmarc-charset-perl (<< 1.2), libscalar-list-utils-perl (<< 1:1.38), libsocket-perl (<< 2.> 013), libxsloader-perl (<< 0.17)

It provides `perlapi-5.20.0`. What does `libuuid-perl` actually require?

`apt-cache show libuuid-perl`

> Package: libuuid-perl
>   Version: 0.05-1
>   Depends: perl-base (>= 5.18.1-2), perlapi-5.18.1, libc6 (>= 2.4), libuuid1 (>= 2.16)
>   Conflicts: doc-base (<< 0.10.3)

It seems to require not only `perl-base` of version 5.18.1-2 of above, but it *explicitly* depends on `perlapi-5.18.1` which isn't provided.

Further:

`sudo apt-get install libperl5.18`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   libperl5.18 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-7) but 5.20.0-4 is to be installed

`sudo apt-get install libperl5.18 perl-base=5.18.2-7`

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Version '5.18.2-7' for 'perl-base' was not found

Comment: So I understand this is all caused by Perl? There's no way to fix this except by waiting for Perl 5.18.2-7 to be available in the repo?

Comment: I may be wrong, but to me at first sight this does seem like a problem with the dependencies and versions available in the repository. Personally, I'll wait a bit and try updating&upgrading again later - this kind of stuff is kind of to be expected in Sid, the unstable testing "release".

Comment: Yeah I know the risk of the unstable release, I just thought this was a very weird problem (I was expecting bugs in the packages themselves). Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer as soon as it's fixed so someone else can add another answer if there is one.